# Advice on benchmarking my Tile Server (Apache2+mod_wsgi)

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, ubuntu, tile-map-service, apache

I'm wondering what advice people have for benchmarking a tile server?

Specifically, I'm running a TMS using [TileLite](https://bitbucket.org/springmeyer/tilelite/wiki/Home), and Vector Tiles using [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/). Both are running under Ubuntu Server 10.10 / Apache2 / mod_wsgi, using different virtual hosts. Both are pulling data stored in PostGIS, and are caching to disk. I'm displaying these tiles using [Polymaps](http://polymaps.org/).

I'm interested in establishing a benchmark for TileLite and TileStache, then exploring options for increasing their performance/reliability.

I've tried out using [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) on static (individual tiles), but I'm unsure how to simulate a user interacting with the map, causing numerous tiles to be rendered.

Anyways, any tips or sharing of experiences that people have had would be greatly appreciated!

thanks,
matt

N.B. Apparently I can't create new tags like 'TMS' or 'Apache2' because I'm too new to the forum :(

Comment: Thanks for the TileStache link - I had been looking for some way of caching vector data.

Answer (score 8):

As tile caches are pregenerated map images, you will really be testing the underlying map / wms / image server. Unless you are testing against a pregenarated cache, in which case you are testing the web server itself (Apache / IIS etc.).

Stress testing for websites is often done using [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). There was a recent series of posts on using JMeter at http://blog.sourcepole.ch/2011/01/04/jmeter-series/

JMeter was used to benchmark various WMS servers at FOSS4G - http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/FOSS4G_Benchmark - which will be a similar process to benchmarking a TMS server.

Sample code and scripts for each of the WMS servers specified geographic areas can be found at http://svn.osgeo.org/osgeo/foss4g/benchmarking/
Further discussopns on this benchmarking are in the [discussion archives](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/benchmarking/).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive set of links. This definitely gives me a starting point.

Comment: I don't fully agree with the conclusion about uncached case. The tile server is also processing the metatiles which it captures from the image server by splitting them into tile cache which can be quite heavy.