# Testing tools to simulate user map browsing / stress test tile server?

Tags: development, simulation, tile-server, testing

are there any online/offline tools that would simulate user map browsing behavior, possibly concentrating on certain areas or random?

I am trying to stress test a tile server.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/advice-on-benchmarking-my-tile-server-apache2mod-wsgi

Comment: I usually use JMeter